# Add a new filter to see the answers I upvoted previously

Tags: feature-request, answers, upvotes, user-experience, filtering

**Edit Oct 2021:** I made an extension to solve the problem, [Stack Overflow Upvoted Filter](https://github.com/ggregoire/stackoverflow-upvoted-filter-extension).

It often happens that:

1. I have an issue or a "how to do X" question (I might have had that issue before)
2. I search a solution via my favorite search engine
3. I find a question on Stack Overflow (I might have seen that question before)
4. It has a lot of answers, I scroll over them, read them, maybe even try them
5. A few answers later (might be 5, 10, 15…), I find an answer I upvoted previously
6. I try that specific answer and it indeed solves my issue

So the problem here is that:

- the UI doesn't show me any hints that I upvoted an answer for that question, so I have to repeat the process of checking every answer until I find one with the upvoted arrow
- I might just miss an answer that I upvoted previously if it's at the bottom of the list, or miss several ones if I upvoted several answers and stop after encountering the first one

**I'd like to propose a new `upvoted` filter that would:**

- **appear only if I upvoted at least one answer**
- **show the answers I upvoted first**

I made some mockups to illustrate the idea:

The new filter option:

[image: The new filter]

The answers once the new filter is selected:

[image: The answers once the new filter is selected]

Comment: The browser should tell you if you have visited a page before. The 'contrast' for that can be made much clearer: *[How can I change link colors in Firefox and Chrome, but leave all other colors and fonts as they are?](https://superuser.com/questions/638250/how-can-i-change-link-colors-in-firefox-and-chrome-but-leave-all-other-colors-a/638257#638257)*

Comment: Everything else there is done as a sort. How about having a checkbox to filter for answers you've upvoted to appear before - then you can additionally sort by active/oldest/votes?

Comment: Allowing bookmarks to apply to answers would likely be a more elegant way of accomplishing this goal

Comment: The biggest downside to this is you can't undo that vote, if the post hasn't been edited. The vote is long-term, just because you found the answer useful 6 years ago doesn't mean it's at all relevant today. If this were instead just bookmarks, you could alter them irrespective of the post's quality/usefulness to end up with a collection of answers you wanted to keep within reach

Comment: How would you sort the subgroup that is displayed? Say there are 10 answers and you've upvoted 5. How would those 5 answers be sorted? Score? Age of your upvote? Etc. Also, hiding answers that don't fit would probably be a non-starter... they'd just be shown below the answer(s) you *have* upvoted.

Comment: [People don't remember they have answered something](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/26?m=8725274#8725274) and you want to be reminded that you voted something? Shouldn't you be able to, if you visit the page years later, find the best solution at the top? What happens if the solution you upvoted isn't the best anymore?

Comment: As @KevinB suggested, I also believe a new kind of bookmarks is another possible solution for this. In the meantime, you can at least ***follow*** an answer which can later be easily found from your profile under followed posts...

Comment: "the UI doesn't show me any hints that I upvoted an answer for that question, so I have to repeat the process of checking every answer" Well, that's just not true; it shows the upvote arrow in a different color, as shown in your screenshot. It doesn't show on the question, and it doesn't order anything differently, but it certainly shows at least one hint.

Comment: @GG. Your "update" should be an answer.

Comment: **Would be even better if they just improved their search and would have that filter there** imo. But i agree it would be extremely useful because searching on so can be faster than searching in you own notes. Additionally: to all those saying this would be stupid or similar: i think many, me including, only upvote the really useful and best answers anyways and second: the fact that any previously visited links are already colored in html is not of any use when having searched many similar questions that popped up before finding the right answer somewhere on here.